# Format error, operation not executed in WPS using SAS language

Tags: sas, dataformat

Good afternoon.

Data description first:

```
if cell = . , rightfully blank
if cell = yyyymm, missing value needs to be imputed
if cell = 0 or other numeric value, number of days
```

I have monthly data from January 2010 to November 2016. I need to derive the missing values based on the available data. I don't touch change anything if it **should be blank** but if it's **missing, I need to derive it**.

Here is my code (I've changed the variable names because it might be confusing):

```
data trial3;
set work.trial2;
if currentmonth=. Then currentmonth=.; else do;
        if currentmonth=201001 then do; 
            if nextmonth=0 then currentmonth=0; 
            else do; 
                if nextmonth ne 201002 then _201001=nextmonth-31; 
                if currentmonth<0 then currentmonth=0; 
            end; 
        end; 
end;
```

There's no error notification but the log would just end running and every line it did run is preceded by an exclamation point.

Comment: Your code does not have any syntax errors, but it has a number of logical errors.  Please add to your question, to show 5-10 records of sample data from work.trial2, and also show the desired output you would want for work.trial3.

Comment: Post the log and at least some sample data so we can test the code ourselves.

Comment: Hello @Quentin. Yes, I realized that it was the order that's wrong. I needed to start from the last column going to the first. Thank you very much for responding. The code now looks like:

Comment: data trial3;

set work.trial2;

if _201611=. Then _201611=.; else do; if _201611=201611 then _201611=0; end;

if _201610=. Then _201610=.; else do;if _201610=201610 then do; if _201611=0 then _201610=0; else do; if _201611 ne 201611 then _201610=_201611-30; if _201610<0 then _201610=0; end; end; end;
if _201609=. Then _201609=.; else do;if _201609=201609 then do; if _201610=0 then _201609=0; else do; if _201610 ne 201610 then _201609=_201610-31; if _201609<0 then _201609=0; end; end; end;
...run;

Thank you to @Reeza for responding as well.